# How do I draw Convex Defects

Tags: c#, image-processing, computer-vision, emgucv

I'm doing my final project about hand gesture recognition using EmguCV. So far I did until Convex Hull. Now, I want to draw convexity defect on it and get the defect value from it. But I am stack. I found some references codes, but most of it written in C++ code. I don't how to convert them into c# code. Anyone, Would you mind to help me by convert this code? this is the C++ code:

```
for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
{
    size_t count = contours[i].size();
    if( count <300 )
    continue;

    vector<Vec4i>::iterator d=convdefect[i].begin();
    while(d!=convdefect[i].end()) 
    {
        Vec4i& v=(*d);
        int startidx=v[0]; Point ptStart( contours[i][startidx] );
        int endidx=v[1]; Point ptEnd( contours[i][endidx] );
        int faridx=v[2]; Point ptFar( contours[i][faridx] );
        float depth = v[3] / 256;
        line( drawing, ptStart, ptEnd, Scalar(0,255,0), 1 );
        line( drawing, ptStart, ptFar, Scalar(0,255,0), 1 );
        line( drawing, ptEnd, ptFar, Scalar(0,255,0), 1 );
        circle( drawing, ptFar,   4, Scalar(0,255,0), 2 );
        d++;
    }
}
```

thanks,

Comment: Please [SEE THIS](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html#contours-more-functions). If it doesn't help let us know.

Comment: The problem is to convert the code to c#.I searched everywhere for weeks   but unfortunately i didn't find anything that can help me  !

Comment: What's this convdefect[i]? what is its data type?